# Bash script: print a certain line based according certain parameteres based on an input line

Tags: bash

I'm pretty new to bash. What I want to achieve is printing a certain line according to certain parameters with one input line.

This is the best example I could come up with. Let's say I have a movie script. It consists of five people talking to each other, let's call them Mary, Laura, Joe, Michael and Louis. Now: I hear one line of Louis. I want to find the closest Mary line to the one I've just heard (and it must be "upwards", it must come before Louis's line, not after). The movie script is set in this manner:

```
MARY: line1
LAURA: line2
JOE: line3
MICHAEL: line4
LOUIS: line5
```

Okay, now

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Type Marys line:
read marysline
grep -rIH "$marysline"
```

This is *maybe* how the script could begin? Not sure. I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: I completely don't understand what is going on here. What should the output be? What _exactly_ is the input? The input is `MARY: line1` or `line1`? The output should be?? There is no previous line before line1?

Comment: You need to pass in the name of teh file containing the lines you want to search. So, if the file is called movies.txt you should `grep -IH "$marysline" movies.txt`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Sorry, I really wasn't being clear. The input line should be `line5` or `LOUIS: line5`, it's indifferent. The output should be `MARY: line1`. So, the input is a certain line of the movie script and the output is the closest Mary line (the Mary line should come BEFORE the certain line, not after) to that certain line.

Comment: Yes, there are lines before `line1` and after `line5`. It was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

> The input line should be line5 or LOUIS: line5, it's indifferent.
>
> the input is a certain line of the movie script
>
> the output is the closest Mary line (the Mary line should come BEFORE the certain line, not after)

1. Print all the lines up until a pattern is matched. This is simple with sed.
2. Reverse with tac.
3. Print the first match of Mary line. Simple with grep -m1

Example:

```
# recreate input
input="LOUIS: line5"
cat >play.txt <<EOF
MARY: line1
LAURA: lin2
JOE: line3
MICHAEL: line4
LOUIS: line5
EOF

# the script
# Print all the lines up until a pattern is matched.
sed -n '1,/'"$input"'/p' play.txt | 
# reverse order of lines
tac | 
# match the first Mery line
grep -m1 -i '^Mary:'
# or grep -m1 "^MARY:", no idea is non-sensitive match is intended
```

would output:

```
MARY: line1
```

Tested on [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/TenderConsciousNonagon)

Actually, you could do it all in `sed`. For the lines up until `$input`, remember the lines with Mary in hold space, and just print the hold space on the last line of input. As the hold space will hold the last Mary line, it should be fine. (The script could be also speed up by doing `q` before `$`, so it doesn't has to parse the whole file):

```
sed -n '1,/'"$input"'/{ /MARY:/{ h } }; ${ g;p }' play.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I think I have to say some things before: that little example was... just an example. There are many many many lines of movie script. Those five lines were just to demonstrate what I wanted to achieve. Plus the input was also an example, it is a variable. Now said, I don't understand the meaning of all the lines after the cat line. Like I've said, the file is very very long (5MB worth of text and code) and pasting everything would be an overkill.

Comment: `pasting everything would be an overkill` then past a significant portion that allows to kind-of unit-test others script. Really a simple 15 lines with 3~5 lines of Mary in different places would be enough.  You don't understand a [here document](https://linuxhint.com/bash-heredoc-tutorial/)? Sorry, there was a bug in `{p;q}` in `sed`.